# Can every group be embedded normally in a group such that its automorphisms are all conjugations?

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Let $H$ be a group. Can $H$ be embedded into a bigger group $G$ such that $H\triangleleft G$ and for every $\varphi\in\text{Aut}(H)$ there exists $g_\varphi\in G$ with $\varphi(h)=g_\varphi hg_\varphi^{-1}$ for all $h\in H$? If so, can it be done in some canonical, or even in some sense minimal way?

This question came up while working on Sylow-groups, but it isn't of any actual use there. I just wondered :)

Comment: Off the top of my head: maybe take the semi-direct product of $H$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ via the identity map $\operatorname{Aut}(H) \to \operatorname{Aut}(H)$?

Comment: I think this actually works :) not bad ;)

Comment: @DanielSchepler That semidirect product has a name. It is called the *holomorph* of the group $H$.